# How to properly mock library to be able to test the component with jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dropzone

I'm tryng to test a component which uses `react-dropzone` library.

```
import TextInput from './components/TextInput';
import Switch from 'react-switch';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
const MyComp = () => {
   return <div>CONTENT</div>
}
```

When I run the test I get:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
    In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

  12 | import TextInput from './components/TextInput';
  13 | import Switch from 'react-switch';
> 14 | import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
```

In `setupTests.js` I try to mock it as other libraries:

```
// Mock custom hook useDimensions
jest.mock('./hooks/useDimensions.js', () => ({
  useDimensions: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    ref: { current: null },
    dimensions: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    isFirstLoad: true
  })
}));

// Mock react-dnd
jest.mock('react-dnd', () => ({
  useDrop: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{ handlerId: 'mockHandlerId', isOver: false }, jest.fn()]),
  useDrag: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{ isDragging: false }, jest.fn()])
}));

// Mock react-dropzone
jest.mock('react-dropzone', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-dropzone'),
  useDropzone: jest.fn()
}));
```

But I keep getting the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't reproduce, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

More like:

```
import * as reactDropzone from 'react-dropzone';

const mockedUseDropzone = jest.fn();

jest.spyOn(reactDropzone, 'useDropzone').mockImplementation(() => mockedUseDropzone);
```

or

```
 jest.spyOn(reactDropzone, 'useDropzone').mockImplementation(mockedUseDropzone);
```

Most of the times you will need "spyOn" in order to mock hooks from libraries [Read more](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).